# Multiple queries MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is there is proper way to do this. I want to calculate the average rating for a table and update the result in another table simultaneously. Im new to PHP and MYSQL and I would appreciate any help

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO review (username, restaurant, rating, review) VALUES ('$username','$restaurant','$rating','$review')");
if($query)
{
    $avg_query="SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating),0) FROM review WHERE name =\"$restaurant\"";
    $avg_result=mysql_query($avg_query);
    $avg_row=mysql_fetch_array($avg_result);
    $rating=$row['ROUND(AVG(rating),0)'];
    if($avg_result)
    {   
        $update_query= "UPDATE restaurant SET rating=\"$rating\" WHERE name =\"$restaurant\"";
        $update_result=mysql_query($update_query);
    }
}
else
{
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like you want a subquerry

Comment: Use parametrised queries! Never insert a variable directly into a query string! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE restaurant 
SET rating= (SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating),0) FROM review WHERE name ='$restaurant')
WHERE name ='$restaurant'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would combine the two into one like this:

```
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO review (username, restaurant, rating, review) VALUES ('$username','$restaurant','$rating','$review')");
if($query)
{
    $avg_query="UPDATE restaurant a SET rating=(SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating),0) FROM review WHERE name =a.name) WHERE name ='".$restaurant."'";
    $avg_result=mysql_query($avg_query);
}
else
{
}
```

Having said that, you should move over to either PDO or mysqli as the `mysql_*` functions are depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a mysql [`trigger`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html). For example (don't hold me to the syntax):

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_review
AFTER INSERT ON review
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE restaurant 
    SET rating = (SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating),0) FROM review WHERE name = NEW.restaurant)
    WHERE name = NEW.restaurant;
END
```

Again as mentioned by others use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).